# Custom WordPress theme creation-display specific posts on home page

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, posts

How to display specific post on my home page?

I would like to display "featured" category which I created so first 50 words of each post are displayed?

Thanks guys

Comment: you can use get_posts() function and pass category ..for ex.category id is '3' so code is $args=array('category'  => 3);$str=get_posts($args);print_r($str);

Comment: another way is create custom post type and retrieve that post by provide 'post_type' argument in get_posts(); ..for Ex ..custom post type is 'movie' so code is $args=array('post_type' => 'movie');$str=get_posts($args);print_r($str);